# How to get first day of year in KDB/Q?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I'm looking for efficient function to get the first day of year in Q. Like `2017.05.10 -> 2017.01.01` or `2016.08.19 -> 2016.01.01`.

The next snippet works, but it is not efficient

```
{"D"$(string `year$x),".01.01"} .z.d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common trick in this kind of calculations is to use the fact that unlike dates, months are very regular: each year has exactly 12 months.  Thus to find the first day of the year, we first cast the date to the month type, then round it down to the multiple of 12 and cast back to the date type:

```
q)f:"d"$12 xbar"m"$
q)f .z.d
2017.01.01
```

or with the OP's dates:

```
q)f 2017.05.10 2016.08.19
2017.01.01 2016.01.01
```

Answer (score 3):

for some of the range of "d":

```
q)"d"$ceiling 365.245*-2000+`year$.z.Z
2017.01.01
```

(dates are days from y2k)

Comment: I think this example may work for most given dates but if I feed it any date in the year 2290 it gives me the second date of the year.

Comment: Change 365.245 to 365.2425 if you care about such dates. (Or see my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw another variation into the mix:

```
q){.Q.addmonths[x;1-`mm$x]+1-`dd$x} .z.d
2017.01.01
```

Comment: For completeness see the wiki page on [`.Q.addmonths`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qaddmonths)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for the sake of it:

```
{"d"$1+(-).`month`mm$x}.z.d
2017.01.01
```